# Como actualizar y/o aumentar a horas,minutos en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Quisiera sabes como actualizar/agregar mas o menos horas/minutos a registros en mas de 500 registro, intente realizar un query asi.

```
UPDATE PROVEEDOR.HD_SOLICITUD
SET SO_FECCERRADO = '10/04/2021 08:38:33'
WHERE SO_NUMSOLIC||SO_NUMANO IN 
(
'0004321'
)
```

pero no me resulto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que deseas hacer, edita la pregunta y añade lo que tienes actualmente y lo que deseas obtener.

Comment: ¿Tu consulta actual da error? o ¿Cuál es el problema con ella?

Comment: Y cual es el problema

Comment: A la fecha que se muestra en el campo SO_FECCERRADO, quiero aumentarse mas o menos minutos, mediante un query